# Run functions from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

trying to get the selected values from a list of checkbutton without having to create 10 or more checbutton and var.

i got this to test the idea

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Checkbutton, Button, BooleanVar

root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))



def def1():
    print("1")

def def2():
    print("2")

def def3():
    print("3")

def def4():
    print("4")

def def5():
    print("5")

def def6():
    print("6")

def letssee():
   print(addlist)



nomtestes = ["def1", "def2", "def3", "def4", "def5", "def6"]

clltes = 0
rwwtes = 0
addlist=[]
username_cbs = dict()
for name in nomtestes:
    if clltes == 5:
        rwwtes += 1
        clltes = 0
    username_cbs[name] = Checkbutton(root, text=name, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    username_cbs[name].var = BooleanVar()
    username_cbs[name]['variable'] = username_cbs[name].var
    username_cbs[name]['command'] = lambda w=username_cbs[name]: upon_select(w)
    username_cbs[name].grid(row=rwwtes, column=clltes, pady=2)
    clltes += 1

Button(root, text="OK",command=letssee).grid(column=0, row=5, padx=1, pady=15)


def upon_select(widget):
    if widget.var.get() == True:
        addlist.append(widget['text'])
    else:
        addlist.remove(widget['text'])

root.mainloop()
```

In this example im trying to print all the checkbuttons i selected, but, to run the funcions added to the addlist

Any ideia how to do this?

thanks

Comment: Can you boil the question down to the relevant part? Is it necessary that we see your GUI code and talk about checkbuttons or is the question simply how to call functions from a list?

Comment: i just need to know how to call the function in the addlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary, mapping string values to respective functions, and then add or remove them to a list. You can add a function map and change the `letssee()` like this to check.

```
func_map = {"def1": def1, "def2": def2, "def3": def3, "def4": def4, "def5": def5, "def6": def6}
nomtestes = ["def1", "def2", "def3", "def4", "def5", "def6"]
```

---

```
def letssee():
   print(addlist)
   for i in addlist:
       func_map[i]()
```

---

```
Out:['def2', 'def1']
    2
    1
```

Comment: I need to call the function in the list

Comment: you example gives me error that 'str' object is not callable

Comment: updated answer.